# Google VR View - Head Tracking

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard

So I am using the Google VR `View/Cardboard SDK` for android to display a 360 video in my app. However head tracking doesn't appear to work on either the google sample app or my own one.

**Is there a method or function I am missing that would enable this functionality that they describe?**

This is how I am calling the video into the `VR Video View`:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container,false);
    videoWidgetView = (VrVideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    try {
        videoWidgetView.loadVideoFromAsset("video.mp4", null);
        videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    Button mClickButton1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                videoWidgetView.playVideo();
        }
    });


    setRetainInstance(true);
    return view;
}

//Set title
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("VR Experience");


}
```

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem? I have same problem, head tracking doesn't work on google demo app.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For head tracking to work, the device must have an embedded gyroscope. Coming from iOS I was surprised to see that a significant number of android devices (including the one I was testing on) don't have this. If they don't have one it will only work by swiping.